# Automatically remove a model attribute if another attribute of same model changed in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

So I want to automatically remove a model attribute when a specific other attribute of the same model changed.

I got a rails model named `profile` and it has a `picture` attribute containing an URL to an image in our image store. Additionally the model has a `crop_data` attribute containing information which part of the image to present to the user, which can be set by the user and defaults to `profile.crop_data? # => false`

If the `profile.picture` attribute changed or got removed/reset

```
profile.crop_data? # should return false
```

and be reset to default value in the database.

What is the cleanest way to achieve this? Unfortunately we are still running `Rails 3.2.21`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an before save callback:

```
class Profile
  before_save :check_crop_data


  def check_crop_data
    if self.changed_attributes.has_key?(:profile_picture) 
      self.crop_data = true
    elsif picture.nil?
      self.crop_data = false
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: actually useful first step. but doesn't solve the problem of detecting picture has changed before_save.

Comment: check out my latest revision.  Feel free to update it with your exact logic if need be

Comment: i actually used a different approach hooking into our image stores upload and delete calls, but i think this would have worked pretty fine too. so accepted